# Optimizing Get From Firestore in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting a user's information for their profile page using the code below. My concern is that at any amount of scale, cycling through all of the users and to check for the uid will cause performance issues.

```
db.collection("users").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    if document.get("uid") as! String == uid {
                        let firstNameDisplay = document.get("firstname")!
                        let lastNameDisplay = document.get("lastname")!
                        self.firstName.text = firstNameDisplay as? String
                        self.lastName.text = lastNameDisplay as? String
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My Firestore has the following structure:

[image]

I'm sure there is a more efficient way to get to the specific user without looping through all of the documents. Does anyone have suggestions on how to implement that efficiently?

EDIT: Adding `signUpPressed`

```
@IBAction func signUpPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //Create the user
    if let email = emailTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines), let password = passwordTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) {

        let firstName = firstNameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let lastName = lastNameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let emailAddress = emailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { user, error in
            if error != nil {
                print("ERIC: Unable to authenticate with Firebase using email")
                print(error!)
            }
            else {
                let cleanPassword = self.passwordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

                if isPasswordValid(cleanPassword) == false {
                    print("Password does not meet the requirements! Please revise.")
                    return
                } else {

                    //Create cleaned versions of data

                    print("ERIC: Successfully authenticated with Firebase")
                    if let user = user {
                        let userData = ["provider": user.user.providerID]
                        let uid = user.user.uid
                        self.completeSignIn(id: uid, userData: userData)
                        let db = Firestore.firestore()
                        db.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["lastname":lastName,"firstname":firstName,"email":emailAddress,"uid":uid]) { (error) in
                            if error != nil {
                                print(error!)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch a single document by its `documentId`:

```
db.collection("users").document(uId).getDocument() { ... }
```

...assuming the `documentId` is the `uid` (which is often a good idea). If it isn't, you can query for a single document by a single field:

```
db.collection("users").whereField("userId", isEqualTo: uId).getDocuments() {
    // should return 1 document
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I want the `documentId` and the `uid` to be the same but they are not (see screenshot). I added my `signUpPressed` function. How would I change the `signUpPressed` to ensure `documentId` is equal to `uid`?

Comment: Just use the UID when you create the user to create the associated documents.